# How many recursive calls does it take to compute binomial probability weights?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recursion

I was given an algorithm and I was asked to estimate how often it would be called if I was trying to calculate ${100 \choose 50}0,25^{50}0.75^{50}$, the Binomial distribution of $50$ elements chosen within $100$ elements with $0.25$ their probability to appear.

This is the method:

```java
binomial1(int N, int k, double p) {
    if (N == 0 && k == 0) return 1.0;
    if (N < 0 || k < 0) return 0.0;

    return (1.0 - p) * binomial1(N-1, k, p) 
         + p * binomial1(N-1, k-1, p);  
}
```

The question is, how many calls to `binomial1` would be required to evaluate `binomial1(100, 50, 0.25)`?

I tried first the fool strategy to implements a `system.out.println` within the code with an indice increasing each time the algorithm was called. But I realised that it was something fool when I noticed I reached:

```
passed 2485266 times
```

Thus I was wondering that as far that the algorithm is called twice every time it is called, I was wondering if it was simply called $2^{100}$ times? Yet, `p*binomial1(N-1, k-1, p)` seemed to be called only $50$ times with a parameter $k=50$...

I'm only asking for a hint.

Comment: Are you looking for a formal analysis here, or for guidance on how to run meaningful experiments?

Comment: a formal analysis of how much this algorithm should be called.

Comment: In that case, check out our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis). Basically, you'll get a recurrence relation which you then [have to solve](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers). Print-line counters will never get you there, but can be useful for forming and testing hypotheses; for instance, *do* you observe powers of two for small `N`?

Comment: You don't need a formal analysis to answer the question how often binomal1 is called when you invoke binomial1(100,50). You can write a program to calculate this value. This program must be more efficient than binomial1, e.g. by remembering the values already calculated.

Answer (score 2):

If we let $T(n,k)$ represent the number of times that `binomial1` is called when computing `binomial1(n, k, p)` we'll have $T(n,k) = T(n-1, k) + T(n-1, k-1)+1$ and $T(-1, k) = T(k, -1) = T(0,0)=1$. The closed form expression for $T(n,k)$ is a bit messy, but fortunately we don't need it.

Note that the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ are defined by the nearly similar recurrence $\binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-1}{k-1}$ so we'll have $T(n,k)\ge \binom{n}{k}$ and in particular $T(100, 50)\ge \binom{100}{50}$ and by Stirling's approximation we'll have $T(100,50)\approx 2^{100}/\sqrt{50\pi}$, which is pretty much what you guessed.

[In fact, it turns out that $T(n,k)$ is quite a bit larger than $\binom{n}{k}$.]

Comment: that is a very strong hint

Answer (score 1):

Hint1:

Try to figure out by hand the invocations of binomial1 for similar, but smaller numbers, e.g. `binomia1l(4,2,p)`, `binomial1(10,5,p)`, or for not so similar number pairs like `binomial1(10,7,p)`.

Hint2:

You don't need a formal analysis to answer the question how often binomal1 is called when you invoke binomial1(100,50). You can write a program to calculate this value. This program must be more efficient than binomial1, e.g. by remembering the values already calculated.